# notepad++ Open current dir cmd using 64 bit cmd

Tags: cmd, notepad++

When I `Open current dir cmd` it opens a 32 bit cmd. This is a problem because I have a 64 bit `java 8` and `javac 8` in `program files` but running `java` defaults to the 32 bit `java 7` in `program files (x86)`.

Without manually opening a 64 bit `cmd` or installing a 32 bit `java 8`, is there a way for me to quickly make and test simple programs this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open 64-bit cmd.exe from a 32-bit application by running `c:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe`. Just modify your current entry in shortcuts.xml or add another one specifying full path.

Comment: editing shortcuts.xml fails but a new command can be added by the run prompt

Comment: If you try editing shortucts.xml in notepad++ the file will be overwriten with its old version when you close notepad++. To edit this file, you have close all notepad++ instances and edit the file by using other editor, e.g. Windows builtin notepad.exe.